# How to view inbound relationships

Tags: custom-object, fields, relationships, schema

Working with a very large and complex salesforce setup, we have a custom object with several lookup fields to external objects. These are easy to check.

I was hoping there would be an easy way to list all fields which "reference" this object (albeit a lookup or a formula).

I've looked in the Schema Builder, however that just produces an unintelligible mass of lines of which I cannot see how to highlight a single line of differentiate between an "inbound" and "outbound" relationship reference.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can bring all of the fields/objects into Eclipse, and grep search the project.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/describe.php), it will list all child relationships for any object:

[image]

Workbench uses the force.com Describe methods, they are available in [the SOAP API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_list_describe.htm), [REST API](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/resources_sobject_describe.htm) and [Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm).

Comment: Is there any way to find Formula that reference an object or field on an object?

Comment: Out of the box: not that I know. You could download metadata(config) and search the files, either the eclipse IDE or Mavensmate IDE are capable of this.